# SSLEngine giving NEED_UNWRAP after unwrapping server hello done

Tags: java, ssl, jsse, dtls, sslengine

I am using `DTLS1.0` provided by java 9. It successfully generate `Client Hello` and server response back with

```
 1. Server Hello
 2. Certificate
 3. Server Key Exchange
 4. Certificate Request
 5. Server Hello Done
```

Then SSLEngine gives `NEED_UNWRAP`. After unwrapping the packets containing the `Server Hello Done` it again gives `NEED_UNWRAP`. After unwrapping the next re transmitted `Server Hello Done` it again gives `NEED_UNWRAP`. It goes again and again.  But i think it should generate the next handshaking signal by giving `NEED_WRAP`.

If i am wrong, please correct me. Otherwise Why it is happening?

**Trust Manager:**

```
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
    };
```

**SSLEngine:**

```
        char[] passphrase = "123456".toCharArray();//This is the password

        // First initialize the key and trust material
        KeyStore ksKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ksKeys.load(new FileInputStream("keystore"), passphrase);

        // KeyManagers decide which key material to use
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ksKeys, passphrase);


        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("DTLSv1.0");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, null);


        int port2 = Queuemanager.switchMediaHandler.get("192.168.19.148").realPort;
        // Create the engine
        engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine("192.168.19.148", port2);

        // Use as client
        engine.setUseClientMode(true);
        engine.setEnableSessionCreation(true);
```

**Handshake:**

```
    void doHandshake(){
    engine.beginHandshake();        
    SSLEngineResult result; 
    HandshakeStatus handshakeStatus;        
    int appBufferSize = engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize();
    ByteBuffer myAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
    ByteBuffer peerAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
    myNetData.clear();
    peerNetData.clear();

    handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
    while (handshakeStatus != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED && handshakeStatus != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING) {             
        switch (handshakeStatus) {
        case NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN:
            logger.debug("NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN");
        case NEED_UNWRAP:
            logger.debug("NEED_UNWRAP");
            DatagramPacket packet = null;
           if(handshakeStatus == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP ) {
            try {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                peerNetData = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf, 0, packet.getLength());
                peerAppData =  ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
          }else{
               peerNetData = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);
               peerAppData =  ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);
           }


            SSLEngineResult.Status rs;
            result = null;
            try {

                handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                while(handshakeStatus == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP || handshakeStatus == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN) {
                    result = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
                    peerNetData.compact();  
                    handshakeStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();
                 }

                handshakeStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();

                rs = result.getStatus();

            } catch (SSLException sslException) {
                engine.closeOutbound();                    
                break;
            }
            switch (rs) {
            case OK:
                break;
            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                break;
            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                break;
            case CLOSED:
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SSL status: " + result.getStatus());
            }
            break;
        case NEED_WRAP:
            logger.debug("NEED_WRAP");
            myNetData.clear();
            try {
                result = engine.wrap(myAppData, myNetData);
                handshakeStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();
            } catch (SSLException sslException) {
                engine.closeOutbound();
                handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                break;
            }
            switch (result.getStatus()) {
            case OK :                                       

                while (myNetData.hasRemaining()) {
                    //String str = myNetData.toString();
                    byte[] arr = new byte[myNetData.remaining()];
                    myNetData.get(arr);
                    recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(arr, arr.length);
                    recvPacket.setData(arr);

                    try {
                        int port2 = Queuemanager.switchMediaHandler.get("192.168.19.148").realPort;

                        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.19.148");       

                        recvPacket.setAddress(ip);
                        recvPacket.setPort(port2);     

                        socket.send(recvPacket);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //socketChannel.write(myNetData);
                }

            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
            case CLOSED:
            case NEED_TASK:
                 Runnable task;
                 while ((task = engine.getDelegatedTask()) != null) {
                      new Thread(task).start();
                 }
                 handshakeStatus = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                 break;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing this back to front. When the engine says NEED_UNWRAP, *do the unwrap.* Then, *if* that returns BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, do the read and try the unwrap again. Don't just assume you need another read on NEED_UNWRAP. You may be losing data from the `peerNetData` the way you're doing it. And don't create a new `peerNetData` via `ByteBuffer.wrap()` or `.allocate()` either: keep using the same one, and use `put()` to put the datagram data *into* it. Then `compact()` it after every successful engine unwrap.

In other words, do exactly and only what it tells you to do.

The `SSLEngine` is a very difficult thing to get right. Many have tried: few have succeeded. For one working success, that is the basis for a commercial product, see the `SSLEngineManager` class in the source code for my book *Fundamental Networking in Java*, Springer 2006, [here](http://dadaelectronics.com.au/FNJ/FundamentalNetworkingInJava.zip).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do i need to call unwrap again with the previous peerNetData or i need to clear peerNetData and then call unwrap?

Comment: I have updated the code according to your suggestion. Now after couple of unwrap it gives NEED_TASK. After handling that it gives NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN, then if i try to unwrap it gives exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 2. plz have a look.

Comment: You should *never* clear `peerNetData`, and you should never create a new one either via `ByteBuffer.wrap()`. You should `compact()` it after every unwrap. The engine will advance the `position` over data it has processed. I don't see where you have done what I stated in my answer. I don't know what NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN, is but you don't need it. The status is still NEED_UNWRAP from when you last got it. It isn't a new state in any way.

Comment: This is getting too broad to answer further but I've answered similar questions on it before several times.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for quick response. Plz let me try your suggestions.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I am new to this field. And i am really stuck. That's why i posted it.

Comment: No problem, it's a very difficult thing to get right. Many have tried: few have succeeded.

Comment: If you don't mind, Can you plz give any working example link?

Comment: Done, see edit.